# Mailbox not sending e-mails: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When sending a message I can see this in my console:

```
Sent mail to You should add method :mail_email in your Messageable model (2093ms
)
Date: Wed, 07 Nov 2012 14:08:50 +0100
From: mail@myemail.com
to: You should add method :mail_email in your Messageable model
```

And the initializers for the Mailbox gem:

```
Mailboxer.setup do |config|

  #Configures if you applications uses or no the email sending for Notifications and Messages
  config.uses_emails = true

  #Configures the default from for the email sent for Messages and Notifications of Mailboxer
  config.default_from = "mail@myemail.com"

  #Configures the methods needed by mailboxer
  config.email_method = :mail_email
  config.name_method = :name

  #Configures if you use or not a search engine and wich one are you using
  #Supported enignes: [:solr,:sphinx] 
  config.search_enabled = false
  config.search_engine = :solr
end
```

In my user model I have:

```
acts_as_messageable
  def name
    email
  end

 def mail_email
    @mail_email = self.email
 end
```

But I get this error in view when sending a message:

```
 ArgumentError in ConversationsController#reply

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Rails.root: C:/rails/sitesale
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/models/user.rb:17:in `mail_email'
app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:22:in `reply'
```

And the controller method reply:

```
  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
    redirect_to conversation
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
def mail_email(object)
    email
end
```

The **(object)** is important.

Comment: interesting, but why ?

Comment: Thanks, this would have taken hours to sort out alone. I wonder why they didn't put a clearer error message in MailDispatcher#call.